# ios app crashes with phonegap 3.0 and Facebook-connect phonegap plugin

Tags: facebook, cordova, ios7

I'm building an iOS 7 app with a newer Phonegap 3.0. I use the Facebook Connect phonegap plugin and I get it to work. The problem is after some usage of Facebook functions, my iOS 7 app crashes due to low memory. I did not have this problem until I migrate to Phonegap 3.0.

Using Xcode 5's memory allocation and memory leaks detection tools, I manage to track the root cause of the memory issues. It seems that every time I initiate a Facebook function, it calls CDVCommandQueue function and the memory usage jumps couple MBytes. The constant jump in memory usage eventually causes my iOS app to crash or being minimized by iOS itself.

Does anyone see this problem? I'm desperately seeking a solution so please help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the Facebook Connect plugin hasnt been updated for PhoneGap v.3. Keep using v.2.9. until it is.